# invalid character error with jquery and highcharts SCRIPT1014: Invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Trying to do a really basic highchart, but I keep getting the error:  "JavaScript critical error at line 42, column 12.  SCRIPT1014: Invalid character.  I have included jQuery in the header so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Testing with IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () { 
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                }, {
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 7, 3]
                }]
            });
        });​
    </script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: works fine here... try copy/pasting it to a simple text file... you probably copied a invalid character from somewhere (if you used copy/paste to add the JS code)

Answer (score 3):

I got a special character '?' when I copy your code just after the last semicolon.
Try to copy your code in a text editor (notepad++ for me), remove this  character and copy again your page.

It has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I took out the very last ";" in the jQuery block of code and it worked.  Weird...

Answer (score 0):

In the future I advice to use [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/) which check your syntax.